# How to know when all has_many associations have a particular attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following associations:

```
Order has_many Row
Row belongs_to RowStatus
```

I want to be able for Order to know when all its associated Rows have a particular Status. So, in the Row model I have the following callback:

```
before_save bubble_up_status

def bubble_up_status
  if self.row_status_changed?
    self.order.n_reviewed_rows += 1 if self.row_status.name == 'reviewed'
    self.order.n_failed_rows += 1 if RowStatus::failed_names.include?(self.row_status.name)
    self.order.n_pending_review_rows +=1 if self.row_status.name == 'pending_review'
    self.order.check_all_statuses
  end
end
```

And then in the Order model I have

```
def check_all_statuses
  if n_reviewed_rows == rows_count
    update(order_status: OrderStatus.find_by(name: 'reviewed'))
  end
  if n_failed_rows == rows_count
    update(order_status: OrderStatus.find_by(name: 'failed'))
  end
  if n_pending_review_rows == rows_count
    update(order_status: OrderStatus.find_by(name: 'pending_review'))
  end
end
```

I see this problematic as I keep updating an attribute in the parent model (Order) on a before_save, so I can have false positives.

Which pattern could I use to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look for all orders where the rowstatus is not equal to the desired rowstatus. If there are any rows that don't have that rowstatus, you therefore know that all rows **do not** have that rowstatus.

```
ideal_status = RowStatus.find_by(name: 'Completed')
order.rows.where.not(row_status_id: ideal_status.id)
```

If you need to see if all rows have one of a few statuses, just pass an array of the desired status ids.

```
ideal_status_ids = RowStatus.where(name: ['Completed', 'Shipped', 'Received']).pluck(:id)
order.rows.where.not(row_status_id: ideal_status_ids)
```

So, for your case, when you want to do something if each row is 'Completed', you'd use

```
if order.rows.where.not(row_status_id: RowStatus.find_by(name: 'Completed').id).empty?
  # do something
end
```

As for where do use it, I think an `after_save` callback makes the most sense, because what happens if you make a change to your order but the save to row failed for some reason? In addition, you probably only want to make any order changes in `bubble_up_status` if the current row's rowstatus is one of the desired rowstatuses, so you aren't going into the database to check all rows every time you save a row.

```
class Row < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :bubble_up_status

  def bubble_up_status
    ideal_status_ids = RowStatus.where(name: ['Completed', 'Shipped', 'Received']).pluck(:id)
    if ideal_status_ids.include?(row_status.id) && order.rows.where.not(row_status_id: ideal_status_ids).empty?
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

**Alternative Solution**

If an order has a very large number of rows, then reaching to the database to check the row status of each individual row related to an order every time one of that order's rows changes status may not be the most efficient way. So, I'd suggest using a counter cache for `rows_count`, and then adding another column that counts the number of rows with the desired row status.

For the sake of example I'll assume that you're interested in the number of rows whose status has been marked completed. First, we'll add the `rows_count` and `completed_rows_count` columns to the `orders` table. This will be a migration file.

```
class AddCountsToOrders< ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :orders, :rows_count, :integer
    add_column :orders, :completed_rows_count, :integer
  end
end
```

After running `rake db:migrate`, we'll need to adjust our `Order` model, so that it counter caches the row count, and also counts the completed rows. In addition, we'll need to update our `bubble_up_status` callback to use the new columns.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rows, counter_cache: true
end

class Row < ActiveRecord::Base

  # here I'm using after_update because I'm assuming that
  # new rows can't be completed when first created
  after_update :update_completed

  # Needs to be after update_completed
  after_save :bubble_up_status

  def update_completed
    if persisted?
      if row_status.name == 'Complete' && row_status.name_was != 'Complete'
        order.increment!(:completed_rows_count)
      elsif row_status.name != 'Complete' && row_status.name_was == 'Complete'
        order.decrement!(:completed_rows_count)
      end
    end
  end

  def bubble_up_status
    # Check if all order rows are completed
    if order.rows_count == order.completed_rows_count
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

**Additional note**

It's definitely possible to implement this logic with one column, rather than two, but I figured using two columns would be simpler to implement and easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Firstly, the Status is not a string, is an association called RowStatus, which has an attribute called name. And secondly, how do I let the Order know that it needs to check all these statuses whenever a Row status has changed?

Comment: Ah shoot I totally misread you original question. Hopefully my updated answer helps. I'm changing all the references from status to row status now too.

Comment: Updated my answer again to contain references to row_status, rather than status. Sorry again about misreading your question. Hopefully this will work for you though. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: That is really interesting, but imagine that an Order has a lot of Rows, wouldn't it be really expensive to count every time an after_save happens?

Comment: @HommerSmith I added an alternative solution that doesn't count every time a row status is changed to one of the desired statuses. Let me know what you think!